# Proof using modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

> Suppose $n|m$, then $n\cdot d=m,~d\in\Bbb Z$.
>
> If $a\equiv b\mod m$, then $a\equiv b\mod{n\cdot d}$.
>   Additionally, $d\equiv d\mod{n\cdot d}$.
>
> So we know $ad\equiv bd\mod{n\cdot d}$.
>   $\therefore a\equiv b\mod n$

Would this be a valid proof?

Comment: What is the statement that you're proving?

Comment: I'm trying to prove that if n|m where n, m are integers greater than 1, and if a === b (mod m) then a === b (mod n)

Comment: Ok then your argument is valid. But perhaps you need to prove the last line (like, why can you divide everything by $d$, did you prove this in class?)

Comment: I don't think so. So I would need to prove that?

Comment: I think you do, if there's a $k$ such that $ad= (nd)\cdot k + bd$ what can you do next?